# Spring boot with JSPs in executable jar builded with gradle

Tags: java, jsp, gradle, spring-boot

I'm looking for solution how to create with gradle executable JAR from Spring Boot application with JSPs. I found the solution with maven
https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-jsps-in-executable-jars-1

Main idea is to put JSPs to `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp/`. And it works with maven, but not with gradle.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) add to standard spring-boot dependencies:

```
compile("javax.servlet:jstl")   
compile("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
```

2) put JSPs to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`

3) change `application.properties`

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Here is the example repo:
https://github.com/markstein/Labor/tree/master/spring/labor-spring-boot